# How to set Writer permission in Google App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up Wordpress on the Google App Engine following the instructions on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project. I'm a bit stuck at the fourth step of "Prerequisites":

[image]

When I go to **Application Settings**, I see the following:

[image]

I can't find any **Service Account Name** with an e-mail address to add as a user with **Writer** permission. How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Service Account Name" is `wordpress-123922@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. Can double check it by using [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts)